# Druid Long Running Query Times Out with HTTP ERROR 504 Gateway Timeout Exception

Tags: sql, druid

I have a 5 node Druid cluster (1 master, 3 data, 1 query nodes). I am running a query using the Druid UI console. The query runs for a while and times out with the exception "Gateway Timeout" showing on the druid UI.
My query JOINS two tables [table A: 2 billion rows, and table B: 50 million rows].

Is there any setting in druid or the client side to avoid this gateway timeout issue?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked on how to increase the timeout?

- https://support.imply.io/hc/en-us/articles/360034310953-Tuning-Druid-for-Large-Result-Sets?mobile_site=true
- https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/query-context.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have been using these two documents. Did not see any parameters that helped in the gateway timeout issue. Is there any specific parameter you suggest that will help in this case?

Comment: The druid.server.http.defaultQueryTimeout

Comment: Maybe this would be more helpful - https://www.druidforum.org/t/request-failed-with-status-code-504/5665

Comment: I have this druid.server.http.defaultQueryTimeout set in the broker/runtime.properties to 30 min. I still get the timeout issue. I will try this with Query Context. Thank you again.

Comment: I set the timeout in the query context and I see the broker did not die this time but UI console still shows "Gateway Timeout" error message. Unfortunately, this parameter did not help in solving the issue that I am facing.